# Check Final Amount is allowed to accept with Available Denominations of country in PHP

Tags: php

Need to make custom function to check amount with available denominations.
code i make :

```
$amount = 100;
$notes_aval = array(20,50,100,500,2000);//available currency notes
    $is_allowed = 0; //not allowed
    foreach($notes_aval as $note){
         if (fmod($amount,$note) == 0) {
         $is_allowed = 1;//allowed
          }
       }
echo $is_allowed;
```

But this is not working out for all cases. 
For exam : i have denominations = array (20,50);
with amount 90 is not allowed, but it should be allowed by 20*2 + 50*1 = 90

in the example of denominations = array (20,50) ,if amount 1110 should be acceptable with 1110 = 20*53 + 50*1

Comment: Why do you use fmod instead of `%`?

Comment: "But this is not working out for all cases." - What you mean ?

Comment: what is not working? expected input / output ?

Comment: i edited question with not working case.

Comment: to handle floating point modules i used fmod instead of %.

Comment: As an alternative how about permitting any multiple of 10 except 10 and 30,  My maths may be wrong but I think  that any value over 30 that is divisible by 10 can be made by some combination of notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try both modular divisions

```
function validateCurrency($amount)
{
    $requestdAmount = $amount;
    $valueUnder = 0;
    $notes = array(20, 50,100,500,2000); 
    $is_allowed = 0;
    if(in_array($amount, $notes)){
        return $is_allowed = 1;
    }

    $numOccurance = ceil($amount/$notes[0]);
    $arraySums = [];

    foreach ($notes as $key => $value) {

    for ($i=1; $i <= $numOccurance; $i++) { 
            if($value * $i == $amount) { 
                return $is_allowed = 1;
            }
            $arraySums[$key][] = $value * $i;
        }
    }

    for ($i=0; $i < count($arraySums); $i++) { 
        for ($j=$i+1; $j < count($arraySums); $j++) { 
            foreach ($arraySums[$i] as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($arraySums[$j] as $key2 => $toBeMul) {
                    if($value+$toBeMul == $amount) { 
                        return $is_allowed = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return $is_allowed;

}
// Driver Code 
$amount = 40; 
$is_allowed =  validateCurrency($amount); 
echo $is_allowed;
die();
```

It will work

Comment: try with $amount = 70 or 90

Comment: 70 or 90 returns 0, if the value is acceptable it should return 1 right?, working for me as expected.

Comment: 70 and 90 should be acceptable. 20+50 = 70 and 20*2 + 50 = 90

Comment: Hi edited the code please do a test, let me know if not working

Comment: Thanks for update. countCurrency(110) is not working as example. can be allowed by bank with 20*3(notes)+50*1(notes) = 110. right?

Comment: can you do a test on  the new code, I have updated the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to start exchange from largest value until your amount is smaller than largest note (eg 2000). Then you go this same with lower note (eg 500), and again with lower. When amount is smaller than lowest value (eg. 20) then you cannot exchange this amount.

So:

- We start with 2270
- We check for largest note - it's 2000.
- Now we know we have 2000 and 270 (2270 - 2000) rest
- Now we check again for largest value - it's 200
- So we have 2000, 200 and 70 (270 - 200) rest
- Now largest not possible is 50
- So we have 2000, 200, 50 and 20 (70 - 50) rest
- Now largest is 20 and we have 2000, 200, 50, 20 and rest is 0
- As rest is smaller than lowest note then we can stop checking.

If rest is 0 we know we can exchange, if rest is larger than 0 then we cannot. Additionally we also have list of notes we can use for exchange (2000, 200, 50, 20).

```php
function checkDenomination($amount){
    $notes = array(2000,500,100,50,20); //it's easier if they are reversed
    $smallestNote = 20;
    $result = [];

    while($amount >= $smallestNote) { //we will repeat until we can exchange
        foreach($notes as $note) { 
            if ($amount >= $note) { //we check for largest value we can exchange
                $result[] = $note;
                $amount -= $note; //as we have hit, we can deduct it from amount;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return ($amount > 0) ? false : $result; //return false if we cannot exchange this amount or array with notes we can exchange for full amount
}

var_dump(checkDenomination(100));
var_dump(checkDenomination(23424));
var_dump(checkDenomination(25000));
var_dump(checkDenomination(222));
```

Comment: checkDenomination(1110) should be acceptable, bank can manage to exchange amount with 50 and 20 notes by 50*1 (notes) + 20*53(notes). right?

Comment: You got me there. Need to rethink it :)